# I have an array of objects and i want to get the latest createdAt and then apply a filter of date range if it falls in that date and then count it

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61a765e6f664eb8f6b12c"),
    "details" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60c84d9968c2d100154f3391"),
            "expiryDate" : ISODate("2021-06-12T05:30:00.000Z"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-06-15T06:50:01.046Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-06-10T06:50:01.046Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60c84d99c2d100154f3391"),
            "expiryDate" : ISODate("2021-06-25T05:30:00.000Z"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-06-15T06:50:01.046Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-06-16T06:50:01.046Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60c84d9968c20154f3391"),
            "expiryDate" : ISODate("2021-06-25T05:30:00.000Z"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-06-15T06:50:01.046Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-06-15T06:50:01.046Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

How can i write mongo query to sort and get the latest date and then apply date range filter on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `$addFields` an auxilary field `lastCreatedAt` by using `$max`. Then `$match` on the field in an aggregation pipeline.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "lastCreatedAt": {
        $max: "$details.createdAt"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      lastCreatedAt: {
        // input your date range here
        $gte: ISODate("2012-06-16T06:50:01.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2021-12-30T06:50:01.100Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      docs: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      },
      numOfLastCreatedAt: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ICpICL2cKsI) for your reference.

Comment: this only works for one object, I have 100s of _id and corresponding details arrays and apply the same for all of them

Comment: What do you mean by *works for one object* ? Can you elaborate more by providing the test cases and expected output?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/liAn283BS3m
see like i've added one more object so there should be 2 lastCreatedAt fields for 2 objects

Comment: It is about the date range input. Your playground need a more inclusive date range input to include the 2021-12-30 test case. Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XZ-Yw8KmV05) out.

Comment: great!!! thanks, how do i count the number of lastCreated fields?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the *number of lastCreated* fields? Would be helpful if you can give an expected ouptut.

Comment: since i found 2 documents in that query so i want to return 2.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/UpKkJVv8WGD

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ICpICL2cKsI) what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what i was looking for. Can you tell me source/ ref for writing such queries?

Comment: My suggestion is go have a solid foundation of understanding what the aggregation pipeline does and its capability. Check out the [offcial aggregation reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation/). The remaining is just a accumulation experience and it takes time and effort :)